# CakePHP 2.x Timthumb path error within another plugin

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

### Introduction:

I've created a separate back end plugin named "administrator". Within this plugin, I want to use TimThumb. The directory structure is as follows:

```
app/Plugin/
     -Administrator 
         - Model
         - View
           - Merchant
             - view.ctp
             .......... 
         - Controller 
           - AdministratorAppController.php (extends AppController)
         ..........

     - Timthumb
         ........
```

### What I've tried so far:

Within AdministratorAppController, I've written:

```
 public $helpers =  array(......., 'Timthumb.Timthumb');
```

Now, in the view file Merchant/view.ctp, I've written the following:

```
echo $this->Timthumb->imageUrl(
    '/administrator/img/Logo/'.$merchant['Merchant']['logo'], 
    array('width' => 200, 'height' => 100)
);
```

### My issue:

But this generates a url:

```
http://xpertsden.com/projects/infinit_dev/web/administrator/timthumb/image?src=%2Fprojects%2Finfinit_dev%2Fweb%2Fapp%2Fwebroot%2Fadministrator%2Fimg%2FLogo%2FINFINIT_570b7d2ea0a82.jpg&q=80&a=c&zc=1&ct=1&w=200&h=100
```

Note: My image is within the plugin Administrator/webroot/img/Logo/image.png

Can anyone come up with a solution, please?

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no magic way you can do this, however I use the same plugin and I made a few modifications to it to allow it to work a bit better for my usage.

Please view the instructions at https://github.com/voycey/TimthumbPlugin#configuration

You can see that you can edit the configure variable TimthumbBasePath `Configure::write('TimthumbBasePath', '/');`

So before you use the plugin you should be able to do:

`Configure::write('TimthumbBasePath', '/Administrator/webroot/img/Logo/image.png');`

Or whatever the route is required to display image.png.

However having resources in a plugin directory is really inefficient [(Please Read here for why)](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/plugins/how-to-create-plugins.html#plugin-assets) - you should look to move those into the main image directory where possible.

Comment: Thanks, mate. That helped a lot! :)